# AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'sort'

Tags: python

The Task Reads...

> Write a program that takes a list of student names and sorts them to
>   create a class roll. The list of names will be given on a one line
>   separated by a single space.

So I have my code.

```
items=input("Students: ")
items.sort(lambda x, y: cmp(x.lower(),y.lower()))
print(items)
```

Why am i getting this, "AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'sort'" Error"

Cheer's In Advanced

Ronny

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`input()` returns a string. If you would like for `items` to be a list, you can do `item.split()`:

Let's assume `items` is `John Mary Bill`

You can then do:

```
items = items.split()
```

Then do `items.sort()`, as `items` will be a list object, not a string.

Comment: Cheers, you saved the DAY!